# Python Social Auth with Instagram Basic Display API

Tags: django, instagram, python-social-auth

I'm developing an app that lets users see their own social media data.

I'm using python-social-auth with Django and it works great with twitter and facebook.

However, I'm having some trouble getting it working with instagram. The 'authorize with Instagram link' takes the user to the following URL:

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=******&redirect_uri=https://example.com:8000/social-auth/complete/instagram/?redirect_state=******&state=******&response_type=code&scope=user_profile+user_media
```

The user clicks 'allow', at which point python-social-auth produces the following URL and raises an exception:

```
https://example.com:8000/social-auth/complete/instagram/?code=******#_
social_core.exceptions.AuthCanceled: Authentication process canceled
```

I found the reponse object and call response.text to get this output:

```
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"}'
```

I've checked the redirect uri is the same in the Instagram basic display settings. https://example.com:8000/social-auth/complete/instagram/

Any suggestions very welcome!

Thanks

Lloyd

Comment: Did yu set the redirect_url in your facebpook app settings? Are you sure example.com is correct? Usually, django run at http://localhost:8000

Comment: yes, example.com is one of the hostnames I added to ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings. Surely the facebook app settings are unique to facebook and the only relevant settings here are "Instagram App Id", "Instagram App Secret" and the valid redirect uri for Instagram?

Comment: It looks as if Instagram is not accepting the `redirect_state` parameter in that `redirect_uri`, could you try subclassing the auth backend and overriding the attribute `REDIRECT_STATE` with `False`? Then point to this backend in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting.

Comment: Thanks omab that works great!! Problem solved.

Comment: There was an [issue in social_core](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/260) about this case.